# "Hive Runtime Error while processing row" of XML file

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive

I am trying to read a simple xml file and extract the data from it.Below is the file

src:

```
<a>
        <b id="foo">b1</b>
        <b id="bar">b2</b>
</a>
```

i have created the src table in hive as below:

```
Create table src(line string);
```

and then i have loaded this table as below:

```
load data local inpath '/home/hduser/Desktop/batch/hiveip/src' into table src;
```

i am trying to extract the as data by using below query:

```
select xpath(line,'//@id') from src;

    Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"line":"<a>"}
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:195)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"line":"<a>"}
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:550)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:177)
            ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating array ('line',''//@id'')
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:92)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:540)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid expression '//@id'
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathUtil.eval(UDFXPathUtil.java:74)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathUtil.evalNodeList(UDFXPathUtil.java:95)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.GenericUDFXPath.eval(GenericUDFXPath.java:76)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.GenericUDFXPath.evaluate(GenericUDFXPath.java:97)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:166)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:79)
            ... 13 more
```

I am not getting the output.

But, when i have executed the below query i got output:

```
select xpath('<a><b id="foo">b1</b><b id="bar">b2</b></a>','//@id')
```

Output :

```
["foo","bar"]
```

It would be great if anyone could explain me what exactly happening and where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that your table `src` has 4 rows like this.

```
+---------------------+--+
|      src.line       |
+---------------------+--+
| <a>                 |
| <b id="foo">b1</b>  |
| <b id="bar">b2</b>  |
| </a>                |
+---------------------+--+
```

Instead it should be like this

```
+----------------------------------------------+--+
|                   src.line                   |
+----------------------------------------------+--+
| <a><b id="foo">b1</b><b id="bar">b2</b></a>  |
+----------------------------------------------+--+
```

Arrange your xml file in such a way they are in a single row

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cat myxml.xml 
<a><b id="foo">b1</b><b id="bar">b2</b></a>
```

and load it to hive

```
create table src(line string)
location '/your/xml/location';
```

and run your query.  It should give you the expected result

```
+----------------+--+
|      _c0       |
+----------------+--+
| ["foo","bar"]  |
+----------------+--+
```